# Mastermind game python pegs count

Tags: python

i tried to count the no. of exact and partial matches. however, this doesn't seem to work fine. If i enter a color that's in the code 4 times, it will give me 1 black 3 whites which makes no sense at all. What's wrong? Also, i do not want to print the position of an exact or a partial match.
For example, if the computer selected "Red,Green,Red,Blue", and if i say "Red,Blue,Green,Yellow", i want it to give me blacks:1 and whites:2

```
def blacks_whites(code,guessList):  #code is the 4 color combination that the computer generates at random and guessList is the guessed color combination
    blacks=0
    whites=0
    for i in range(len(code)):
        if guessList[i]==code[i]:
            blacks+=1
        elif guessList[i] in code and guessList[i]!=code[i]:
            whites+=1
```

Comment: Your question seems to be vague. What is `code` what is `guessList` suppose to be? Can you provide a [mcve] and show your desired output and input?

Comment: my point was can you provide what `code` is and maybe a few entries of `guessList`, just so we are clear on what's going on. I have guesses but not good enough to provide you a full answer.

Comment: if the code is RYGY, and i guess YYYY, i should get black pegs:2 white pegs:0, if i guess YRYR, i should get black pegs:0 white pegs:3, if i guess RGYY, i should get black pegs:2 white pegs:2

Comment: add some examples which you use to test it, expected results and what results you get.

Comment: if you find color which is on correct place (black) then you have to mark it and don't check when you count whites. And you have to first count all blacks and after that you can count whites

Comment: In the mastermind rules you can't use the same colour more than once...

Comment: BTW: you could create simple "unit tests" like `blacks_whites("RYGY", "YYYY") == (2, 0)`, etc. and then you can fast check if your function work correctly.

Comment: @Joey Can you explain to us in detail, how you know what the black and white values are for the test examples you gave?  I'm **not** asking for the rules, which you explained, but for the process *you* follow in applying those rules.  Because you have a process.  You know that if the code is RYGY and I give you RGBY, how many blacks and whites there will be.  Explain that process in detail, and that's your algorithm.  The problem is not a lack of understanding of Python, but that you haven't articulated to yourself what your task is.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein  okay. I have a code and i have a guess, first i will check if the values in the guess list correspond to the code or not, if they do, i add one to the black pegs. Then i have to check the remaining ones, if they appear in the code apart from the same position, i add one to the white pegs

Comment: That's a start.  Go a little bit deeper, into pseudocode.  "if they do, i add one to the black pegs, then I have to check the remaining ones".  Is that one for loop, or two for loops?  Again, when you do it manually (e.g., telling me that my guess is 2 black, 1 white), how do you personally do it?

Comment: On second thought, don't worry about pseudo code.  Just worry about filling in the process details more specifically.  Explain every step in detail that you personally go through in figuring out blacks and whites.

Comment: i check each color of your guess one by one... if it matches at the right position, black+=1, if not, i check the code if it contains that color which makes white+=1 .... so i guess that should be 2 for loops

Comment: That's a good first step.  At this point with code RYGY and guess RGBY, you've gone through your first loop and realized there are two black pegs.  Now, in the second loop, what part do you look at to figure the white pegs?  One hint to get you started: what's the maximum value for black pegs + white pegs?

Comment: You *do* know, because you're able to do it away from the computer.  That's the whole trick to being a programmer - knowing how to do something in the real world, and "explaining in sufficient detail to a computer for the computer to do it."  Figure out what *you* are doing, and you're well on your way to being a programmer.  At this point though, someone has given you the answer, so I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

This code works with examples but maybe you have other rules and it will not work with other examples

I use `used` to mark elements in `code` which have pair with element in `guessList` so it can't be used with other pair.

```
def blacks_whites(code, guessList):

    blacks = 0
    whites = 0

    used = [False, False, False, False]

    # search only blacks and mark as "used" black elements

    for i in range(4):
        if guessList[i] == code[i]:
            blacks += 1
            used[i] = True

    # search only whites (but skip "used" elements)
    # and mark as "used" every white element in code 
    # so it can't be used twice

    for i in range(4): # guess index
        for j in range(4): # code index
            if not used[j] and code[j] == guessList[i]:
                whites += 1
                used[j] = True

    return blacks, whites

# --- tests ---

data = [ # code, guess, expected result (blacks,whites)
    [ 'RYGY', 'YYYY', (2,0) ],
    [ 'RYGY', 'YRYR', (0,3) ],
    [ 'RYGY', 'RGYY', (2,2) ],
]

for test in data:
    code, guess, expected = test
    result = blacks_whites(code, guess)
    print(code, guess, expected, result, result == expected)
```

Answer (score 0):

How I see it your output makes sense, suppose:

```
code  = RGBY
guess = RRRR
```

The first `R` creates a black peg, right?
Every other `R` *is* indeed in your code (since your method doesn't account for duplicates), so every other R creates a white peg.

I have not time to write source, but I would try to

- create a temp copy of `code`
- use basically for algorithm, but with `temp` not `code`

and

- in every step "delete" the matched color from `code` by putting a `-` or else instead

In the case above (`Code: RGBY, guess: RRRR`) that would result after the first iteration in: `temp: -GBY, guess: RRRR` and the second to fourth `R` aren't matched anymore.